# Install zend on linux server

Tags: zend-framework

I have set up all files on my linux server and index.php file is under pulic_https(usually we have pulic folder for this) folder I see server does not found this file so it give me apache
2 test page.

```
Here is my .htaccess file :
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Here is my application.ini file under appliction/config

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH    "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.layout.layout = "default"

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

database.host = "localhost"
database.username = "sdasd"
database.password = 'dasd'
database.dbname = "asdasd"

autoloadernamespaces[] = "Resources_"
autoloadernamespaces[] = "Plugins"
resources.frontController.plugins[] = "Plugins_ViewSetup"
```

This is structure of whole file on serve

application

-- config

-- application.php

-- controller

-- layout

-- view

css

csvtemp

library

--zend

--plugins

--thumbnail

--resources

Img

public_http

public_https

--.htaccess

-- index.php

--css

-- img

--js

cron

tests
here is site link : http://cct-ars.com

Comment: Provide some more details.

Comment: Yes @indrasinh I added some more detail

Comment: Have you rename your `public folder` ??

Comment: No its default folder.I am using pulic_https from starting...

Comment: I have worked with zf 1.12 and it has `index.php` in public folder. So if you have your `index.php` in public_https than check your `.htaccess`.

Comment: Yes I have .htaccess file and having configuration above
Now What I do I place index.php and include'public_https' in it and debugging.I have .htaccess file under public_http only

Comment: I dont know much about `.htaccess` scripts but index.php is your front controller so your all requests must gone through index.php and `.htaccess` brings all the request to index.php.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by But I don't like the way

```
Create index.php in root and .htaccess
in index.php include public_https and .htaccess configuration same above in question and also change base url function.
```

Now I have question that why.htaccess file and index.php have not access under public_https